# Rounding a BigDecimal in Java doesn't return the expected number

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a property called `m_FOBST` which contains the following number: `1.5776`. Here I'm trying to round it:

```
   this.m_FOBST.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
```

However, I get the number **1.60** when I should be getting **1.58**.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I can't duplicate this, i get: groovy:000> d = new BigDecimal("1.5776")
===> 1.5776
groovy:000> d1 = d.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
===> 1.58

Comment: Try setting scale to 3?

Comment: See http://araklefeistel.blogspot.com/2011/06/javamathbigdecimal-difference-between.html?m=1

Comment: `System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.5776").setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN));` prints `1.58` too.

Comment: As another note, you should use `setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)`, the version you use here is considered a legacy method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BigDecimal` is immutable - make sure you are using the value returned by the `setScale()` method.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("1.5776");

bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```

In this case, `bd` is **1.58**

Comment: He probably is, since he said the answer was 1.60 (and BigDecimal doesn't round anything by default)

Comment: You should always use the `String` constructor when creating `BigDecimal` from a floating point number.

Comment: @Keppil Why do you say that?

Comment: thanks @Keppil - you're right. You do that because `double` and `float` are not exact representation of floating point numbers, this is the first reason why you want to use `BigDecimal`

Comment: @sdoca: Floating point numbers are not exact. Run the following line to see what I mean: `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1.5776));`

Comment: @sdoca Quoting the javadocs: "[...]Note: the results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable [...]" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)

Comment: I copied the exactly same code that you put @manub, and get the correct answer, but i can´t get this using my property.
So I did this
  `BigDecimal bd2 = this.m_FOBST;
  bd2 = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);'
And it worked, thank you so much.